# Do Tracking Disruptors Affect Missiles?

Tags: eve-online

Do tracking disruptor modules or rats with tracking disruptor effects affect missile damage in any way, or do they only affect turrets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they only affect turret-based weapons. Missiles are unaffected.

There were some plans by CCP to change this at some point, but they were not actually implemented. I haven't heard about them in a while so I'm not sure if they are still planning to change this.

Comment: @christian.s This change was planned, but it never went into effect

Comment: You are right - sorry.